# Passing an action property to a JavaScript function

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, properties, struts2

I'm facing a problem with my JSP page, when I try to a Struts2 `<s:property>` value as an argument to a JavaScript function named `handleChange` so that I could save new values of that collection here is my form :

```
<form name="monF" method="get">
    <display:table name="menaces" pagesize="1" requestURI="loadLesCauses.action" decorator="configuration.MyDecorator" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
        <display:column property="idmenace" title="id menace" />
        <display:column property="lienmenace" title="lien de la menace" media="html" />
    </display:table>
    <s:iterator value="causesmenace" status="rowStatus">
        <h3 class="intro-text text-center">
            <strong><li><s:property value="libellecause" /></li></strong>
        </h3>
        <s:hidden id="idcause" value="idcause" />
        <h2 class="intro-text">impact sur metier</h2>
        <s:select id="impact" name="impact_sur_metier" list="impactsurmetier" value="defaultValue_im" onchange="handleChange_impact(this.value,%{#rowStatus.index});" cssClass="form-control"></s:select>
        <br>
        <h2 class="intro-text">niveau de probabilité</h2>
        <s:select id="probabilite" name="niveau_de_probabilité" list="niveaudeprobabilite" value="defaultValue_np" onchange="handleChange_probabilite('<s:property value=" idcause "/>',this.value,%{#rowStatus.index});" cssClass="form-control"></s:select>
    </s:iterator>
    <button type="submit" onclick="radarRisk()" title="radarRisk">radarRisk</button>
</form>
```

**and here is my JS block:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tableName = document.getElementByClassName("menaceList");

    function handleChange_probabilite(id, value, nbr) {
        JSSauvegarderCause.sauvegarderCauseProbabilite(value, nbr, afficherValidation);
        alert(id + value + nbr);
    }
    }
</script>
```

**error message :**

```
févr. 22, 2014 9:27:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
Grave: "Servlet.service()" pour la servlet jsp a lancé une exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /vues/menacesView.jsp(129,70) Symbole égal (equal)                 attendu
```

The code works fine if I delete `<s:property value="idcause"/>` in the `onchange` event.

Answer (score 1):

Struts2 doesn't allow nested tags like `<s:select ... <s:property .../>/>`. You can use OGNL expressions in the tag attributes. When you have used

```
<s:hidden id="idcause" value="idcause" />
```

the value attribute evaluated as OGNL expression, and you need to provide the getter for the actual value

```
public String getIdcause(){return idcause;}
```

Then use a javascript function to get the value from the hidden field

```
onchange="handleChange_probabilite(document.getElementById('idcause').value,this.value,%{#rowStatus.index});"
```

Comment: thanks for your replay, actually there is no more errors on page but getElementById dosn't take the value of the property,

Comment: It's a document function. You have used similar function to get the element by class name, so you should be familiar with this function too.

Comment: there is no class attribute in neither s<property> nor <s:iterator>, adding to that each row has it's own id, so i should pass the argument dynamically

Comment: yes, the code seems incomplete, so do I close the question?

Comment: why? i want to say that i tried to add a class name but, there isn't any, if I posted that question is to having some answers not to close it just like that

Comment: The class name is not related to your question, and if you disagree with my answer, having a code that can't reproduce a problem should be closed.

Comment: I Fixed the probleme, I had to set dynamically the name value using an <s:hidden> like this :
<s:hidden id="id%{#rowStatus.index}" name="idcause"/>
and in the javascript function i use : 
document.getElementById('id'+valeur).value
with valeur : the value of the selected row
thanks